# How do I find other zipcodes that touch a particular zipcode?

Tags: r, zipcode

I want to create a matrix for around 200 zipcodes and neighboring zipcodes that touch those zipcodes. The matrix would be 200*200 with 1's for the cells in which the two zipcodes touch and 0 when they are not neighboring zipcodes.

How could I create or get such a matrix? Thank you very much.

Best,

Comment: There's a zip code shapefile [here](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2013/main), if that helps.

Comment: From what information would you like to construct this? Do you have a shape file? Perhaps coordinates?

Comment: I have access to some of the shapefiles as used by jbaums. But not to all the states that I wanted. I think I could manually input the coordinates of the zip codes if it came down to it. How do you think I should proceed? I wanted the information for 9 states and I was able to get the shapefile for 4 states but not the remaining 5 as I mention below. Please let me know how I can use the lat long information to create this matrix. Thank you very much.

Comment: @danny117 - you're asking a different question in your bounty description, but I think the edits to my post might help.

Answer (score 15):

If you have access to a shapefile, this is relatively straightforward with the help of the `spdep` package.

Here's a standalone example using Californian zip code data (~3.5MB download):

```
# load libraries
library(rgdal)
library(spdep)

# download, unzip and import shapefile
download.file('http://geocommons.com/overlays/305142.zip', {f<-tempfile()})
unzip(f, exdir=tempdir())
shp <- readOGR(tempdir(), 'tigerline_shapefile_2010_2010_state_california_2010_census_5-digit_zip_code_tabulation_area_zcta5_state-based')

# identify neighbours for each poly
nbs <- setNames(poly2nb(shp), shp$ZCTA5CE10)

# convert to a binary neighbour matrix
nbs.mat <- nb2mat(nbs, zero.policy=TRUE, style='B')

# see?rgeos::gTouches for an alternative to the above steps

# assign zip codes as dimension names
dimnames(nbs.mat) <- list(shp$ZCTA5CE10, shp$ZCTA5CE10)
```

For our dataset, this returns a 1769 x 1769 matrix indicating which zip codes are neighbours. The first 10 rows and 10 columns look like this:

```
nbs.mat[1:10, 1:10]

##       94601 94501 94560 94587 94580 94514 94703 95601 95669 95901
## 94601     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
## 94501     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
## 94560     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
## 94587     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
## 94580     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
## 94514     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
## 94703     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
## 95601     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
## 95669     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
## 95901     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Optionally, if you want a two-column matrix giving neighbouring pairs of zip codes (i.e., zip code in col 1, and neighbouring zip code in col 2), you can use the following.

```
nbs.list <- sapply(row.names(nbs.mat), function(x) names(which(nbs.mat[x, ] == 1)))

nbs.pairs <- data.frame(zipcode=rep(names(nbs.list), sapply(nbs.list, length)), 
                        neighbour=unlist(nbs.list))

head(nbs.pairs)

##        zipcode neighbour
## 946011   94601     94501
## 946012   94601     94602
## 946013   94601     94605
## 946014   94601     94606
## 946015   94601     94621
## 946016   94601     94619
```

Comment: Thank you very much jbaums. This is what I was looking for. :-) However I could not find the shape files for KY, MS, NC, SC, TN and VA. Where should I be able to find them. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure that they are available for all states individually at geocommons, but you could try [this](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/ZCTA5/tl_2013_us_zcta510.zip) file, which I imagine has zip codes for _all_ states. (I haven't checked, since it's a 500MB download that I don't particularly need.)

Comment: Also note the difference between ZIP codes and [ZIP code tabulation areas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code_Tabulation_Area). The latter are supplied in the above shapefile.

Comment: Yes I do want the pairs.   This is something I may spend some time on.

Comment: @user3435644 Also: within the former (ZIP Codes) there are Zip Areas (~33,000) and Post Office/Large Value Customers (~10,000). The former are shapes, and the latter are points. Important to know the difference with analysis like this.

Comment: You can download more shapefiles at the [Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html), but it looks like they'll only have the Zip Code Tabulation Areas. This [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77800/shapefiles-for-us-city-and-zip-level) on GIS SE discusses finding zip codes and they had trouble finding (free) zip codes.